# Django model custom methods making query and updating the field

Tags: django, django-models

I have IPAddr model, and I pre populated the table with data(IP address).And it has field *available* by default it's true all ip's available.

```
from django.db import models
class IPAddr(models.Model):
    ipaddress = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ipaddress
    @static 
    def getip(self):
    # what should i do ?    

class Vm(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    instrument = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ipaddr = models.OneToOneField(IPAddr,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=0)
```

So what want to do is I need to call a model methold it's give me the first availble ip and change it's value availble = False.
any suggestions are appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both answers you have recieved are good ones, but there is a small extra step. You need to make sure that this happens in an atomic block. Else you may find that two different instances get the same IP address and lead to IP address conflicts.

```
from django.db import transaction


@staticmethod
@transaction.atomic
def getip():
    # what should i do ? 
    ip = IPAddr.objects.select_for_update().filter(available=True).first()
    ip.available=False
    ip.save()
    return ip
```

note the use of [select_for_update](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update)

Comment: Glad to have helped. If my answer or one of the answers by the others turned out to be correct, please be so kind as to accept it. That's the usual practice here so that someone who lands on the page in future will know what the solution is.

Answer (score 0):

```
@staticmethod
def getip():
    # what should i do ? 
    ip = IPAddr.objects.filter(available=True).first()
    ip.available=False
    ip.save()
    return ip
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
class IPAddr(models.Model):
    ...
    @classmethod
    def getip(cls):
        ip = cl.objects.filter(available=True).first()
        ip.available=False
        ip.save()
        return ip

class Vm(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    instrument = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ipaddr = models.OneToOneField(IPAddr,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=0)


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ip = IPAddr.getip()
        self.ipaddr = ip
        super(Vm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks for you help,